# SQL Server index rebuild cause database growth

Tags: sql-server, index, storage

I have a 80GB database with about 20GB of indices size. Whenever I build the indices online the database file will grow to gain 20GB of unallocated space, and if the unallocated space is less than 20GB then it will grow to reach the 20GB of unallocated space. It's clear for me that the index is being created then the old one is being deleted.

How can I avoid this growth while we rebuild the index online? I tried to turn the `SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON` but this didn't help.

Comment: By definition, rebuilding the index online means *make a copy* (`SORT_IN_TEMPDB` only affects where intermediate sorting happens; SQL Server will still have to allocate the pages in the source database for permanent storage, and in your case maybe there isn't a whole lot of sorting happening). Grow your data file so it always has room to rebuild the index, then this shouldn't really be a problem. If it's still a problem, you need to pick what's more important to you: not temporarily using that space, or not performing the operation online.

Comment: That all said, [you should still use the `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188281.aspx) IMHO, unless `tempdb` is already a performance bottleneck.

Comment: This site may help you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2812884